# After sending text to Clipboard I get errors in some programs

Tags: windows, delphi, clipboard

Problem is happening in windows 7, although I've not tried to replicate it in other systems. I am using:

```
  while Count <> SL.Count do
  begin
      SysUtils.Sleep(200);
      Clipboard.AsText := SL[Count];
      sendmessage(Appwin,WM_PASTE,0,0);
      sendmessage(Appwin,WM_PASTE,0,0);
      Keybd_event(VK_TAB, 0, 0, 0);
      inc(Count);
  end;
  SL.Free;
  Clipboard.AsText := TextoCompleto;
  EditTexto.SelectAll;
```

TextoCompleto is a string, with just text/numbers;

And sometimes after using that program I get this error message in Adobe Reader latest version 11 (I have a feeling that it did happen in other programs, but not 100% sure) when I try to ctr+c in it:

```
"There was an error while copying to the Clipboard. An internal error occurred."
```

What could be the cause? Perhaps because I am definning clipboard as text?

Comment: You've given one line of code, with no information about half of it (what is `TextoCompleto`?), and no more information except "I get errors in some programs" with no details about the errors or programs. We can't really help you with "Here's a problem with no information. Please guess all the things that might be wrong" type questions. You need to [edit] to provide **specific** information, such as the actual problem you're having, and what "errors" and "some programs" are (we can't see your screen or read your mind) if you want us to help you.

Comment: I've edited. The question is really very simple. I believe it has something to do with setting the clipboard content as text and then adobe trying to copy "material" to clipboard which is not of text type?

Comment: You've made a minor improvement, but you did not provide information about the error ("I get errors" is *not* useful information unless you tell us what the errors are). There's nothing wrong with using `Clipboard.AsText` and then another application trying to use it as something else. If you want help, you need to provide details. Otherwise, answers are just guesswork, and that's not how StackOverflow works. (See the [faq] and [about] pages for more details. Questions here need to be specific, and "please guess what might cause this error I won't tell you about" isn't specific.)

Comment: Problem is the error occours randonmly, so I even tried to make it happen so that I could copy paste the error content but it hasn't happened as yet. As soon as I get it I will give you details. But as far as I remember it's something like "Error copying content to the clipboard".

Comment: The single line of code you've posted will not cause that issue, so there's more going on than what you've included here. (And if you can't reproduce the problem, there's no way we can help you solve it, because we clearly can't do so in order to try to find a solution.)

Comment: I've made it happen again, the exact message in Adobe Reader is "There was an error while copying to the Clipboard. An internal error occurred."

Comment: Ok. How do *we* make it happen? What you've posted is that it's an internal Acrobat Reader error.

Comment: Ken, it happens when after using the program I try to copy some text in Acrobat.

Comment: Are you using any remote desktop connections or virtual machine sessions or other forms of clipboard sharing? I've had this numerous of times (in Adobe Reader, Office and many other programs). None were related to Delphi code: basically it happens when you do two clipboard modifications in short time. During that time, the clipboard synchronization is still doing work and keeps the clipboard of one or more machines locked.

Comment: No, i'm not remote desktop connected or using virtual machine sessions, but the app do modify clipboard content 4 times in a raw at 200ms intervals.

Comment: As @KenWhite mentioned, it would help to see all the code that is used to access the clipboard (e.g., it sets the clipboard content 4 times in 200ms intervals).  So, it's setting the clipboard content for roughly 800ms.  Is it possible that your app is setting the clipboard contents at the same time you are copying in Acrobat (e.g., two apps trying to set the clipboard contents at the same moment)?

Comment: James please see my answer to Jereon down there. I will update the OP with more code.

Answer (score 1):

What happens that is you access the clipboard so often, that other applications have virtually no chance to access it. They get an "Access Denied" error when they try to access it at the same time your application is writing to it. Some applications then immediately fail with an error message to the user (in stead of retrying a few times).

You should cut down the locking time and the access frequency of the clipboard as it is a shared resource.

Please read [How can I fix "Cannot open clipboard: Access Denied" errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859102/how-can-i-fix-cannot-open-clipboard-access-denied-errors), especially the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859102/how-can-i-fix-cannot-open-clipboard-access-denied-errors/4671301#4671301) by [Chris Thornton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/289135/chris-thornton) of which I am quoting this:

> This may have to do with how Vista/Win7 deal with clipboard viewer
>   notification. While they still support the XP "clipboard viewer
>   chain", which sends one notification message that must be re-sent to
>   each listener in turn (and if one app fails to do this, the other apps
>   aren't notified). Starting with Vista, apps are notified directly. And
>   there's nothing to keep them from trying to access the clipboard all
>   at once.

It means that as of Windows Vista the pressure on the clipboard can be higher than under Windows XP, and applications should be more careful accessing it.

Comment: Yes, the thing is my application only access the clipboard 4 times in a raw as I've said, and in a 1 second period. That error is happening much later, minutes later, when I try to copy something in Adobe. Could it be a lethargic defect?

Comment: The best way to check that is to have *only* your application and Adobe Reader running. **Please also edit your question** to mention what version of `Adobe Reader` and `Windows` you are using, and what the purpose of `AppWin` and `Keybd_Event` is. Like the other commenters, I have the feeling your question is incomplete.

Comment: Hammering on the clipboard is never good... I suspect that your rapid clipboard actions are causing some other app (neither your app nor Acrobat) to fail while monitoring the clipboard, and it's holding the clipboard open.  After that, nothing can access it.  Try this: reproduce the issue, then open up two instances of notepad.  See if you can copy from one and paste into the other. I suspect that this will fail. If so, we can stop worrying about which version of Adobe you've got....